# I run Scone in Hardware Mode but occured a problem(Enclave terminated due to signal: Illegal instruction)

Tags: docker, sgx, enclave

I'm running an open source code based on Scone and SGX1.

When I run Scone in Hardware Mode, I occured a problem. The details are shown in picture:
[image]

I don't know how to solve it.

I guess it is due to the SGX version, because the source code is running on SGX1, and the SGX version on my computer may be 2. Does Scone support SGX2 now? Which versions of Scone support it?

Or is my guess wrong and the problem lies somewhere else?

If anyone can help me I would be grateful.

I try many dreffent Scone cross compiler containers, but didn't solve it.

Comment: You don't seem to have included any details in this question other than an image attachment.  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including the source code you've written and the actual commands you're using to running it?